# Count blank cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I'm having difficult for generate a formula to count the blank cells in a range of cells.

So here is the example, the output is expected in the second row and the counting area is in the first row.
I would like the to count the blank cells between the "AAA"s and every cells of output row has a value.

[image]

I have tried "countblank" and "counta", but apparently they don't work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rScYH.png)

Comment: Why do you say `CountBlank()` does not work? Do you get an error message, which one, do you get a wrong result, which one and what's the expected result?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

[image]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=MATCH("?*",C1:Q1,0)
```

Dragged right to `P1`.

For any input, including numbers:

```
=MATCH("?*",C1:Q1&"",0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for this help !! It works with the text for the first row, but what if I want to put different numbers in the first row please ?

Comment: Please update your question with what it is your are actually trying.

Comment: I just did with the link, thank you

Comment: Then use `=MATCH("?*",C1:$Q1&"",0)` instead @ZihanZHANG

Comment: Thanks, it works with other cells, but the last one is N/A, is this normal please ?

Comment: @ZihanZHANG, means you dragged it one cell too far.

Comment: So instead of =MATCH("?*",C1:$Q1&"",0) I may use  =MATCH("?*",C1:$R1&"",0) ? Seems it doesn't change other value and works with the last cell as well

Comment: @ZihanZHANG, no just don't drag till `Q2` since it's the end of the data at `P2` in your case. See your desired results... the two rows don't allign but have a one-cell offset.

Comment: Well I dragged to P2 and when I meant last one I meant P2 who doesn't work, that's why I was asking

Comment: Right, you are correct then. You can also just drop the semi-absolute reference. @ZihanZHANG